# decrease, XOR operator (--) on if and for statement

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, operator-keyword

I'm a newbie who  trying to understand an algorithm from a C++ code , after that I want to implement it in java, but i found difficulties in understanding the code, here 3 pieces of code that confused me

```
inline Edge *Node::NextEdge( Edge *prev)
       {
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
          prev = (Edge *) ( (int) prev ^ (int) edge[i] );
       return prev;
       }
```

//***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

```
if (nextfrag)
      {
      if ( --nextfrag->degree)
         new_frag( nextfrag, fragnum, len, edge );
```

//***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

```
for (pedge = edge; pedge->parent; pedge = pedge->parent);
```

my question for the 1st code: how the iteration work in bitwise Xor operation? what is `prev = (Edge *) ( (int) prev ^ (int) edge[i] );` mean? and  what is the value of return `prev` ?
question for 2nd code : how the decrease operator `if ( --nextfrag->degree)` works in if statement ?
3rd code : is there any other way to to write that for statement? and please explain to me the mean of that for statement, because as a newbie I just use to i= 0; i= something; i++

sorry for stupid question but your explaination will help me so much , thanks in advance :)

Comment: 3: `Edge pedge = new Edge(edge); while(pedge.getParent() != null) {/*...*/ pedge = pedge.getParent();}`

Comment: 1 is casting pointers to int, does xor and casts the result back to a pointer. And that can fail on a 64bit system if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @zapl but somehow I read that the implementation of Xor in this situation isn't mean to cast the object into an int, its something about " if that two object is different then return 1" , thats why i'm confused

Comment: It looks to me like it is not casting the object but the pointer / the memory adress of that object into an int. But beware, my C skills are bad :)

Comment: You are using pointers, but tagged the question "Java"?

Answer (score 0):

```
prev = (Edge *) ( (int) prev ^ (int) edge[i] )
```

(Edge *)  is casting the result as a pointer to an Edge object (or struct )

```
( (int) prev ^ (int) edge[i] )
```

The expression is casting the pointer 'prev' (an Edge), to an int and XORing with the array element edge[i] (not sure the type since this variable is out of scope - but assumption is it's an array of pointers to edges). The pointer (address) size is int. Not sure what the algorithm is, but it seems to assume this will result in a new valid pointer address to another Edge for the next iteration.

```
--nextfrag->degree
```

In this case, decrementing the degree member pointed to by nextfrag, which is a pointer to a struct that has a 'degree' member.

```
for (pedge = edge; pedge->parent; pedge = pedge->parent);
```

this will loop through the linked list until pedge->parent == 0 (the head node in the linked list)

This code is very reliant on the structures being packed on word boundaries.
Pointers (addresses) are 32 or 64 bit, so this is pretty bad code unless you are absolutely certain of the target computer it will run on, since without explicitly packing your structures, it could result in different results between 32 or 64 bit machines. See "#pragma pack".

That doesn't make it any easier to understand.

Comment: '--nextfrag->degree' is not decrementing the pointer, it is degcrementing the 'degree' member that 'nextfrag' is pointing to.

Comment: can I say it like this: `if` after decrementing the `nextfrag->degree != 0 then {//..}` ?